# Remotely locking a workstation is not working, why?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So about a year ago, I discovered [this PowerShell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/cfbc642e-9a1e-4739-9ac5-9f462343a2f7):

```
Function Lock-Workstation 
{ 
param( 
$Computername, 
$Credential 
) 
    if(!(get-module taskscheduler)){Import-Module TaskScheduler} 
    New-task -ComputerName $Computername -credential:$Credential |  
    Add-TaskTrigger -In (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 30) | 
    Add-TaskAction -Script ` 
    {  
    $signature = @"  
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]  
    public static extern bool LockWorkStation();  
"@  
    $LockWorkStation = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature ` 
                                -name "Win32LockWorkStation" ` 
                                -namespace Win32Functions ` 
                                -passthru  
    $LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null 
    } | Register-ScheduledTask TestTask -ComputerName $Computername ` 
                                        -credential:$Credential 
}
```

I cannot get it working. I get all kinds of weird errors. It starts with errors about not being able to find the terminating "@, and once I get that fixed it starts throwing errors in the TaskScheduler module, specifically that it cannot load the type [__ComObject] (which is used in a couple of the TaskScheduler scripts, and I can't find any documentation on it).

I am trying to get this working in PowerShell v2.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT 1:

So I've done some more testing, and it appears that technically it is working (there was a typo in the TaskScheduler module that was causing it to fail completely), but despite the task being scheduled on the remote workstation, the execution of that task fails, kinda. Frequently the task will "run" but with no results, despite having the credentials of the currently logged on user.

EDIT 2:
Downvotes? Really? I'm having issues, I've described the errors I am getting, and rather than offer a suggestion you downvote the question? What is this, Reddit?

Comment: Post the PowerShell code you are using, and the errors you are getting.

Comment: Dammit, there was a link there. sorry, I'll edit.

Comment: So I've done some more testing, and it appears that technically it is working (there was a typo in the TaskScheduler module that was causing it to fail completely), but despite the task being scheduled on the remote workstation, the execution of that task fails, kinda.

Frequently the task will "run" but with no results, despite having the credentials of the currently logged on user.

Answer (score 0):

can't test your code at the moment but you may want to use a simpler approach (not tested):

```
... | Add-TaskAction -Script { rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation }
```

Comment: This works on the local workstation, but still does not work on a remote workstation.

Comment: Have you tried putting the command in a remote scheduled task?